# Called by Open Cover, Nunit Runner Console throws NullReferenceException and hangs forever

Tags: jenkins, opencover, nunit-console

In my project, I use Nunit 2 framework.
In the build server, I use Open Cover 4.6.519 to analyze the code coverage with the following command:

```
    "OpenCover.4.6.519\OpenCover.Console.exe" 
    -target:"..\..\Packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.4\tools\nunit-console-x86.exe"
    -targetargs:"/nologo /framework:net-4.0 /process:multiple /domain:multiple /noshadow /nothread <the_list_of_test_assemblies>"
    -filter:"+[*]* -[*.Test]* -[*.Stub]* -[Deedle]* -[FSharp]*" -hideskipped:Filter -register -output:Build\OpenCoverResult.xml`
```

This is the result I get:

```
    Executing: D:\Jenkins\workspace\SC Nightly\Packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.4\tools\nunit-console-x86.exe
      ProcessModel: Multiple    DomainUsage: Multiple
      Execution Runtime: net-4.0
      Unhandled Exception:
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.CountTestCases(ITestFilter filter)
         at NUnit.Util.AggregatingTestRunner.CountTestCases(ITestFilter filter)
         at NUnit.Util.AggregatingTestRunner.Run(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter, Boolean tracing, LoggingThreshold logLevel)
         at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
         at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)
      Committing...
      Visited Classes 0 of 617 (0)
      Visited Methods 0 of 4030 (0)
      Visited Points 0 of 11734 (0)
      Visited Branches 0 of 6814 (0)

      ==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====
      Alternative Visited Classes 0 of 671 (0)
      Alternative Visited Methods 0 of 4663 (0)
```

I see an null reference exception thrown by Nunit runner, but it seems that OpenCover hangs after Nunit runner stopped.

I am thinking of some potential reasons:

1. The amount of test assemblies is large (59 dll files)
2. The assemblies are built in .Net Framework 4.5, but the framework argument of Nunit runner is net-4.0
3. I am using Nunit 2 which is out of date. (It is very expensive for me to upgrade to Nunit 3)
4. There might be something wrong with my Jenkins. I use Jenkins to run an .msbuildproj file which containing a task to execute OpenCover. **When I run OpenCover command on Windows Command Prompt, it works well.**

Comment: Remove filter and run the command again.

Comment: I change .Net framework argument of Nunit Runner to net-4.5 and it works well